# Why does calling CreateGraphics() change the look and feel of my form?

Tags: winforms, look-and-feel

In my C# winforms application, I am using the Graphics object to obtain the current DPI value to enable my code to scale certain components.  This works fine except that, as soon as I call CreateGraphics(), the look and feel of my winforms application changes.  The style goes from the familiar "rounded" buttons to the more archaic looking "sharp edged" buttons.

Why is this happening and what can I do to prevent it?

My code looks like the following:

```
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        try
        {
            if (g.DpiX == 120.0f)
            {
                // scale the components appropriately
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            g.Dispose();
        }
```

In fact I can reproduce the problem just by calling CreateGraphics and then instantly disposing of it.

Any help or insight much appreciated!

And alternative question is: is there anyway to obtain the DPI setting without creating a Graphics object?

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the DPI problem some time ago, when a colleague started working with a high-DPI display.

My apporach was to ask the Desktop, not a specific window for the Dpi. As I run into some troubles, I came up with this code (not pretty, but worked for me quite well):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Assesses the Systems Primary Monitor's DPI value
    /// </summary>
    public static double DPI {
        get {
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero);
            IntPtr desktop = g.GetHdc();
            int LogicalScreenHeight = GetDeviceCaps(desktop, (int)DeviceCap.VERTRES);
            int PhysicalScreenHeight = GetDeviceCaps(desktop, (int)DeviceCap.DESKTOPVERTRES);

            float ScreenScalingFactor = (float)PhysicalScreenHeight / (float)LogicalScreenHeight;

            // dpi1 answers correctly if application is "dpiaware=false"
            int dpi1 = (int)(96.0 * ScreenScalingFactor);
            // dpi2 answers correctly if application is "dpiaware=true"
            int dpi2 = GetDeviceCaps(desktop, (int)DeviceCap.LOGPIXELSX);

            return Math.Max(dpi1, dpi2);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static private extern int GetDeviceCaps(IntPtr hdc, int nIndex);

    private enum DeviceCap {
        VERTRES = 10,
        DESKTOPVERTRES = 117,
        LOGPIXELSX = 88,

        // http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/GetDeviceCaps.html
    }
```

I especially don't like the hack using the `Math.Max(dpi1, dpi2)`, but for now I found no better solution.

As for your original Question, on Win10 I see no change in visuals. Sorry, no idea here.